# automate kinit while login using sssd

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I'm searching and trying this for a few weeks. What I've done so far: I'm authenticating for login using sssd with ldap. This works actually great!

We need to authenticate via sssd with ldap, because the AD is deep nested. Any other authentication methods were taking too long to login the user.

Now we need to authenticate in some situation with kerberos. A "kinit" and typing my password is enough therefore. But: we would appreciate an user-friendly login (Single Sign-On), so we need to build an automated kinit process.

The credentials are always the same (for kerberos, ldap ...)

As OS we use Ubuntu 14.04, the LDAP/AD is maybe a Windows Server 2008 R2, which is unaccessable for us.

Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible outside using auth_provider=krb5 or auth_provider=ad. The internal kinit process is wired into the sssd krb5 provider, which is also used by the ad provider.